# VS 2008 Lost all Project Templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Soon after I tried installing Expression Studio three times, and had to do a system restore each time, suddenly my Visual Studio lost nearly all its project templates (except for Other Project Types).  When I try an run a repair off the install disk, it says it cannot load files and is cancelling the install.  Anybody have any experience for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is documented by Microsoft.  It is caused by the installer cache 'overtaking' the actual installer database on the install disk.  The solution is to run the installer from Add/Remove programs instead.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily not. A deinstall/install cycle seems to be your best option then.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem but I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116(VS.80).aspx

devenv /installvstemplates

It worked, but took a good 10 minutes to get the job done...